# JSON + LazyLoad

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

Guys, I'm havin a problem with this...

My User class has a property UserType userType like below:

```
    public class User
{
    public virtual int  Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string User { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType userType { get; set; }
}
```

I can't return a JSON, like this...

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult JSONUsers(string q)
    {
        IEnumerable<User> model = dataServ.Users.GetUsers( q );
        return this.Json( new { Result = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
    }
```

I'm getting an error:

> A circular reference was detected
>   while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.

The reason I'm getting this error is the Lazy-Load (at least that's what I understood), and to poorly solve it, I did:

```
public JsonResult JSON(string q)
    {
        List<User> model = new List<User>();
        IEnumerable<User> users= dataServ.Users.Getusers( q );

        foreach (var item in users)
        {
            User user = new User
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Name = item.Name
            };
            model.Add( user );
        };

        return this.Json( new { Result = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
    }
```

---

I don't think this is a good solution. In this case I only need de "Id" and "Name" properties, but what if I need all properties? Will I have to copy one by one?
Can Anybody tell me if there is a better solution?

Thanks,

Thiago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ayende wrote a great [series of blog posts](http://ayende.com/blog/4807/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-the-case-for-the-view-model) about this problem.

But to summarize: **USE VIEW MODELS** => and by the way that's the solution to more than half of the questions on StackOverflow about ASP.NET MVC that I am answering.

Comment: Ok, I can use a view model, but then I'll have 2 similar classes. Is this a really good option? Tks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Thiago Guttierre, you won't have the circular reference between them. So, yes they will be similar (that's where [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) comes in handy) and are considered best practice when working with ASP.NET MVC.